# Extend list by repeating values up to a fixed range

Tags: python, list, append

I have 3 lists of different ranges and would like to align the range by repeating the sequence of numbers for the lists with lower ranges. At the end, all lists should have the range 50. List 2 currently has a range of 30. Hence, the first 20 elements have to be repeated to reach 50. List 3 currently has a range of 15. Hence, the list will be repeated twice completely and the third repetition will cease after 5 elements (50-15=35 elements to be filled).

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
import numpy as np

a1, a1_ = np.array([0, 14, 39, 49]), np.linspace(0, 49, 50)
Y1 = np.array([0, 2.5, 2.5, 1.25])
a2, a2_ = np.array([0, 7, 19, 29]), np.linspace(0, 29, 30)
Y2 = np.array([0, 8, 8, 5])
a3, a3_ = np.array([0, 4, 9, 14]), np.linspace(0, 14, 15)
Y3 = np.array([0, 10, 10, 8])

Y_int1 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(a1, Y1, k=1)
Y_int2 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(a2, Y2, k=1)
Y_int3 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(a3, Y3, k=1)

Y_ = [Y_int1(a1_), Y_int2(a2_), Y_int3(a3_)]

# A working, but not elegant, solution for the second list is:
Y_[1] = np.append(Y_[1], [Y_[1][0:len(Y_[0]) - len(Y_[1])]])

# However for Y_[2] this does not work as the entire list has to be repeated (2.33 times).
```

Comment: The repeated list should look like `[a, b, c, a, b]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

L = 50
arrs = [np.linspace(0, 49, 50), np.linspace(0, 29, 30), np.linspace(0, 14, 15)]
arrs = [np.r_[np.tile(a, L // len(a)), a[:L % len(a)]] for a in arrs]
```

Content of `arrs`:

```
[array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
         11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,
         22.,  23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,  30.,  31.,  32.,
         33.,  34.,  35.,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.,  40.,  41.,  42.,  43.,
         44.,  45.,  46.,  47.,  48.,  49.]),
 array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
         11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,
         22.,  23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,   0.,   1.,   2.,
          3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,
         14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.]),
 array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
         11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,   0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,
          7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,   0.,   1.,   2.,
          3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,
         14.,   0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.])]
```

*Breakdown*

- [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) literally "tiles" an array, that is, it concatenates several copies of the same array. Here `np.tile(a, L // len(a))` tiles as many times as the integer division of the desired length `L` and the array length `len(a)`; for 50 it would be 1, for 15 it would be 2, for 60 it would be 0.
- `a[:L % len(a)]` takes a slice from the beginning of the array up to `L` modulo its length. This is the final "partial copy" of the array that you need to fill up to `L` elements. For 50 it would be 0, for 15 it would be 5, for 60 it would be 50. In all cases, note that obviously `len(a) * (L // len(a)) + (L % len(a)) = L`, meaning that the result of concatenating these two pieces will always have size `L`.
- [`np._r`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) is just an abbreviated syntax for, in this case, concatenate along the first dimension. Here, it is equivalent to `np.concatenate([np.tile(a, L // len(a)), a[:L % len(a)]])`.

Comment: This seems to do what I need to do, but I do not really understand what it does. Could you explain the syntax of the last line?

Comment: @Kevin I've added some explanation, let me know if you still don't think it's clear.